# Always open links from other apps in "N Tabs"?

Tags: safari, tabs

Clicking on a link in another app when Safari is open to a tab group other than "N Tabs" (that must have a name) opens a new window rather than switching the "N Tabs" and opening a new tab there (as it does on iOS). Is there a setting to fix that?

Answer (score -1):

Workaround: drag the link from the external application onto the "new tab" (+ icon) at the top of the preferred Safari window. The link will open in a new tab in this (tab group or other) window.